# RuntimeWarning: GPIO.setup(pin_rst,GPIO.OUT)

Tags: gpio, python

My python script was executed in the past 10 days without issues. I had to do some troubleshooting to find what is causing the problem.

Here is part of my code where the issue is caused:

```
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

def Employee():
   try:
       reader = SimpleMFRC522()
       
       cardData = reader.read()
       
       employeeId = cardData[1].strip('\x00').strip()
       print(employeeId)
       return employeeId[1:len(employeeId)]
   except:
         pass
   finally:
         GPIO.cleanup()

Employee()


RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.
**GPIO.setup(pin_rst, GPIO.OUT)**
```

I did some research but I couldn't find the solution for my problem.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What research did you do?  What does the documentation for RPi.GPIO say?

Comment: to add finally:GPIO.cleanup(); about GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT) - which it didn't fix the problem. RPi.GPIO it points out to use GPIO.cleanup() in the end of the function.

Comment: It is futile posting code fragments. Post real executable code. Frankly this just looks like poorly structured code. If you don't want to correctly terminate your code try gpiozero which does it automatically (and is easier to use)

Comment: @Milliways the purpose of this function just to read the number from the card and print it. As I said, this function was ok for 10 days.

Comment: Your code fragment does NOT have a valid termination. GPIO.cleanup() does NOT belong in a function. All this would do is run once and exit (incorrectly) so the function seems superfluous.

Comment: He is a reference: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/

Comment: After couple hours of troubleshooting I concluded that the cable that is connecting the Raspberry pi and the RFID has a lose connection. I would have to replace this cable.

Comment: I will point out that the warning message (the subject of your question) is  not caused by a loose cable.

Comment: @joan actually it was caused by the loose cable, now the application is working smoothly.